# Check if root of cubic equation is complex or not?

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision, complex-numbers, math.net

I use [this Cubic root](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/RootFinding/Cubic.cs#L108) implementation.

I have equation #1:

```
x³ -2 x² -5 x + 6 = 0
```

It gives me 3 complex roots ({real, imaginary}):

```
{-2, 7.4014868308343765E-17}
{1 , -2.9605947323337506E-16}
{3 , 2.9605947323337506E-16}
```

But in fact, the right result should be 3 non-complex roots: -2, 1, 3.

With this case, I can test by: apply 3 complex roots to the equation, it returns non-zero result (failed); apply 3 non-complex roots to the equation, it returns zero result (passed).

But there is the case where I apply both 3-complex roots and 3-non-complex roots to the equation (e.g. `47 x³ +7 x² -52 x + 0 = 0`), it return non-zero (failed).

I think what causes this issue is because of this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Evaluate all cubic roots of this <c>Complex</c>.
/// </summary>
public static (Complex, Complex, Complex) CubicRoots(this Complex complex)
{
    var r = Math.Pow(complex.Magnitude, 1d/3d);
    var theta = complex.Phase/3;
    const double shift = Constants.Pi2/3;
    return (Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(r, theta),
        Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(r, theta + shift),
        Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(r, theta - shift));
}
```

I know that floating point value can lose precision when calculating (~1E-15), but the problem is the imaginary part needs to decide weather it's zero or non-zero to tell if it's complex number or not.

I can't tell the user of my app: "hey user, if you see the imaginary part is close enough to 0, you can decide for yourself that the root's not a complex number".

Currently, I use this method to check:

```
const int TOLERATE = 15;
bool isRemoveImaginary = System.Math.Round(root.Imaginary, TOLERATE) == 0; //Remove imaginary if it's too close to zero
```

But I don't know if this method is appropriate, what if the TOLERATE = 15 is not enough. Or is it the right method to solve this problem?

So I want to ask, is there any better way to tell the root is complex or not?

Comment: Note that a cubic equation always has 3 roots (counting with multiplicity) and either 1 or all 3 of these roots are real. In particular, it is always guaranteed that at least one of the roots is real.

Comment: The sign of the quantity `D = (B*B - 4*A*A*A)/(-27*a*a)` tells you whether there are three real roots or a single real root and a pair of complex conjugate roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298971/check-if-root-of-cubic-equation-is-complex-or-not#comment127731050_72298971).

So according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation):

> delta > 0: the cubic has three distinct real roots
>
> delta < 0: the cubic has one real root and two non-real complex
> conjugate roots.

The [delta](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/4b13ff4a5e7014997075df34a84d61f10bdd27b3/src/Numerics/RootFinding/Cubic.cs#L114) `D = (B*B - 4*A*A*A)/(-27*a*a)`

My ideal is:

- delta > 0: remove all imaginary numbers of 3 roots.
- delta < 0: find the real root then remove its imaginary part if any
  (to make sure it's real). Leave the other 2 roots untouched. Now I
  have **2 ideas** to find the real root:

**Ideal #1**

In theory, the real root should have imaginary = 0, but due to floating point precision, imaginary can deviate from 0 a little (e.g. imaginary = 1E-15 instead of 0). So the idea is: the 1 real root among 3 roots should have the imaginary whose value is closest to 0.

Code:

```
NumComplex[] arrRoot = { x1, x2, x3 };

if (delta > 0)
{
    for (var idxRoot = 0; idxRoot < arrRoot.Length; ++idxRoot)
        arrRoot[idxRoot] = arrRoot[idxRoot].RemoveImaginary();
}
else
{
    //The root with imaginary closest to 0 should be the real root,
    //the other two should be non-real.
    var realRootIdx = 0;
    var absClosest = double.MaxValue;
    double abs;

    for (var idxRoot = 0; idxRoot < arrRoot.Length; ++idxRoot)
    {
        abs = System.Math.Abs(arrRoot[idxRoot].GetImaginary());
        if (abs < absClosest)
        {
            absClosest = abs;
            realRootIdx = idxRoot;
        }
    }

    arrRoot[realRootIdx] = arrRoot[realRootIdx].RemoveImaginary();
}
```

The code above can be wrong if there are 3 roots ({real, imaginary}) like this:

```
{7, -1E-99}
{3, 1E-15}//1E-15 caused by floating point precision, 1E-15 should be 0
{7, 1E-99}//My code will mistake this because this is closer to 0 than 1E-15.
```

Maybe if that case does happen in real life, I will come up with a better way to pick the real root.

**Idea #2**

Take a look at how [the 3 roots calculated](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/4b13ff4a5e7014997075df34a84d61f10bdd27b3/src/Numerics/Complex32.cs#L501):

```
x1 = FromPolarCoordinates(r, theta);
x2 = FromPolarCoordinates(r, theta + shift);
x3 = FromPolarCoordinates(r, theta - shift);
```

3 roots have the form (know this by tests, not proven by math):

```
x1 = { A }
x2 = { B, C }
x3 = { B, -C }
```

Use math knowledge to prove which one among the 3 roots is the real one.

Trial #1: Maybe the root `x1 = FromPolarCoordinates(r, theta)` is always real? (failed) untrue because the following case proved that guess is wrong: `-53 x³ + 6 x² + 14 x - 54 = 0` (Thank [Mark Dickinson again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298971/check-if-root-of-cubic-equation-is-complex-or-not/72308080?noredirect=1#comment127762334_72308080))

I don't know if math can prove something like: while `delta < 0`: if `B < 0` then x3 is real, else x1 is real?

So until I get better idea, I'll just use idea #1.

Comment: In the case where there's only one real root, you can compute that root using only real arithmetic, avoiding the complex numbers entirely. See [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula).

Comment: @MarkDickinson : Thank you. I just come up with new idea to pick the real root among 3 roots (check my edited answer). I want to ask: is my idea #2 correct? (x1 is always real)

Comment: Not sure. I'd be suspicious of the case where the input `B` to the cube root operation is negative: in that case, it doesn't look to me as though the first root is the real one.

Comment: @MarkDickinson : Thank you again (I edited my answer). Sorry but I want to ask again: Can we tell which one among the 3 root is the real one? e.g., by checking the input: while `delta < 0`: if `B < 0` then `x3 is real` else `x1 is real` (of course this is wrong because I saw a case where `B<0` but `x1 is real`)?.